# How can I create input that accepts Latex syntax?

Tags: html, reactjs, web, input

I'm creating a project that the administrator adds mathematical questions to the system and for that it is necessary to put mathematical formulas

I did some research and saw that Latex is an option

My project is being developed in react

Comment: Look into something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-katex

Comment: you can use mathquill to solve it